# Installing wiki.js on virtual machine

Tags: node.js, npm, virtual-machine, node-modules, npm-scripts

```
[root@localhost html]# node -v
v6.17.1
[root@localhost html]# npm -v
3.10.10
```

I want to install wiki.js on virtual machine, it is based up on node.js and I don't work with node.js but I want to install it for further usage.

based on wiki.js installation document :
https://docs.requarks.io/en/install/linux

I have installed the wiki successfully until step 5 as it says : `node server` and when I run it it says :

```
[root@localhost html]# node server
/var/www/html/server/core/config.js:66
  async loadFromDb() {
        ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/server/index.js:14:14)
```

my `config.yml` :

```
db:
  type: mysql
  # PostgreSQL / MySQL / MariaDB / MS SQL Server only:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  user: root
  pass: msfdjk
  db: wiki
  ssl: false
  # SQLite only:
  storage: path/to/database.sqlite
```

I change the db type from postrage to mysql and enter the user and password and db name and then run the

`node server` command.

I'm a php programmer and I don't know about node.js. How can I install?

wiki.js on virtual machine.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the Node.js version? The `v6.17.1` seems pretty old

Comment: @sebastian-kaczmarek  i really don't know , i just installed it , let me upgrade it and will see what happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Node version seems pretty old. You have to upgrade Node to at least version `7.6.0` where the support for async functions has been added. I would recommend upgrading to the latest LTS tho if that's possible